# Flutter extent scroll

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I have a list of images that I want to distribute into two columns of an avatar circle, with one column taking half of the images and the other column taking the rest of the images.

I put a simple example of code how can I apply that to it? Also how to handle the length of the list?

I don't want to duplicate the images, just divide them while keeping the same UI shape

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class AddUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddUserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddUserPage> createState() => _AddUserPageState();
}

class _AddUserPageState extends State<AddUserPage> {
  final List<String> profiles = [
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-05_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-04_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-01_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-02_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-03_orig.png'
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                squeeze: 1.4,
                itemExtent: 150,
                diameterRatio: 9,
                onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
                physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                  childCount: profiles.length,
                  builder: (context, index) => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(profiles[index]),
                      ),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: AssetImage(profiles[index]),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide `childCount` half of list length,

```dart
childCount: profiles.length ~/ 2 + profiles.length % 2,
```

While presenting right item, you need to check if it exists on list,

```dart
CircleAvatar(
  key: ValueKey(profiles[index]),
  radius: 50,
  backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profiles[2*index]),
),
if (2 * index + 1 < profiles.length)
  CircleAvatar(
    key: ValueKey(profiles[index + 1]),
    radius: 50,
    backgroundImage:
        NetworkImage(profiles[2 * index + 1]),
  ),
```

And those are network image.

```dart
class AddUserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AddUserPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AddUserPage> createState() => _AddUserPageState();
}

class _AddUserPageState extends State<AddUserPage> {
  final List<String> profiles = [
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-05_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-04_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-01_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-02_orig.png',
    'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-03_orig.png',
    // 'http://www.the-able-company.com/uploads/3/2/0/9/32099781/5kids-05_orig.png',
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              height: 250,
              child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                squeeze: 1.4,
                itemExtent: 150,
                diameterRatio: 9,
                onSelectedItemChanged: (value) {},
                physics: const FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
                  childCount: profiles.length ~/ 2 + profiles.length % 2,
                  builder: (context, index) => Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: [
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 50,
                        backgroundImage: NetworkImage(profiles[2 * index]),
                      ),
                      if (2 * index + 1 < profiles.length)
                        CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 50,
                          backgroundImage:
                              NetworkImage(profiles[2 * index + 1]),
                        ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: A method where the length of the list is displayed in the correct way but there are duplicate images please check

Comment: can you check the update, you can remove those key, not needed here

Comment: My brother, try to put additional pictures inside the list, and you will find that he repeats some of them

Comment: does it still happen on update snippet ?

Comment: Yes, you are the only one who gave me a close answer. I hope you complete your favor

Comment: ok, let me refine my logic , can you include the items number that causing issue?

Comment: Add one different image from the internet at a time and do a hot reload, you will understand what I mean

Comment: I've tested even & odd cases, seems working fine.

Comment: What a genius you man, I can't find words to thank you!

Comment: I took the full code below, did you add the ValueKey or not?

Comment: no, not needed here. is it duplicate from your last question? if so, you can delete the old

Comment: Yeasin are you there?

Comment: yes, I am active

Comment: If you notice that there are two circles that are enlarged at the same time when scrolling, I want when onTap on one of them to make a specific event, onTap does not work

Comment: Can you modify the code to do that?

Comment: You can wrap the `CircleAvatar` with GestureDetecture

Comment: It is not working my friend i have tried it

Comment: You can create new question with minimal snippet that reproduce the issue